# Implementation of agent based model

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement an agent based model in python (without using the Mesa package) as practice. I've written code that describes an observer (containing all the agents) which can help the neighbour agents and tells each agent to do a step. The step is saved in a new list before its copied to a list containing the previous situation.

The agents (domain models essentially) are either of the type: 'T' (Tree), 'S' (Soil), 'B' (Burning tree) and 'Bd' (Burned tree).

The concept is simple: we start with a number of trees, a number of burning trees and the rest is soil.
- Soil doesn't burn.
- Trees that have been burned remain burned trees
- Burning trees ignite the trees directly next to it (left, right, up or down) and become burned trees in the next step
- Trees remain trees unless they get ignited by a neighbouring burning tree.

Below the code for this. I've had a few versions but none seem to work. When I run the below version I get an error.

```
import os
import sys
from copy import deepcopy
import random

# observer class
class Obs:
    def __init__(self, max_iters=10):
        self.agents = []
        self.max_iters = max_iters

    def run(self):
        self.history = []
        self.prev_agents = None
        self.iters = 0

        while self.iters < self.max_iters:
            print(self.iters)
            self.history.append(deepcopy(self.agents))
            self.prev_agents = deepcopy(self.agents)
            for agent in self.prev_agents:
                agent.step()
            self.iters += 1

    def add_agent(self, x, y, agent_type, num_agent):
        self.agents.append(
            Agent(
                agent_type=agent_type,
                x=x,
                y=y,
                observer=self,
                agent_id=num_agent
            ))

    def get_neighbours(self, x, y):
        # items do not move so use current_situation
        nbs = []
        for agent in self.agents:
            if (abs(agent.x-x) == 1) & (abs(agent.y-y) == 1) & (abs(agent.x-x) == abs(agent.y-y)):
                nbs.append(agent)
        return nbs

    def set_agent(self, index, agent):
        self.agents[index] = agent

    def changed(self, agent_id):
        if self.prev_agents[agent_id].agent_type != self.agents[agent_id].agent_type:
            # been changed, can't change it back so skip it
            return True
        return False

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, agent_type, x, y, observer, agent_id):
        self.agent_type = agent_type
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.observer = observer
        self.agent_id = agent_id

    def step(self):
        # perform action
        if self.agent_type == 'B':
            # burning
            nbs = self.observer.get_neighbours(self.x, self.y)
            for nb in nbs:
                if nb.agent_type == 'T':
                    self.observer.set_agent(
                        nb.agent_id,
                        Agent('B',
                          nb.x,
                          nb.y,
                          nb.observer,
                          nb.agent_id))

            # set to burned
            self.agent_type = 'Bd'
            self.observer.set_agent(
                self.agent_id,
                self)
        elif self.agent_type == 'T':
            if not self.observer.changed(self.agent_id):
                self.observer.set_agent(
                    self.agent_id,
                    self)
        else:
            # nothing happens to soil or burned trees
            self.observer.set_agent(
                    self.agent_id,
                    self)


xsize, ysize = 10, 10
num_trees = 40
num_burning = 10
num_soil = (xsize * ysize) - num_trees - num_burning

items = ['T'] * num_trees + ['B'] * num_burning + ['S'] * num_soil
random.shuffle(items)
observer = Obs(10)

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    x = i % xsize
    y = i // xsize
    observer.add_agent(x=x, y=y, agent_type=item, num_agent=i)

observer.run()
```

The error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-74779de210e4> in <module>
    104     observer.add_agent(x=x, y=y, agent_type=item, num_agent=i)
    105 
--> 106 observer.run()

<ipython-input-26-74779de210e4> in run(self)
     20             self.prev_agents = deepcopy(self.agents)
     21             for agent in self.prev_agents:
---> 22                 agent.step()
     23             self.iters += 1
     24 

<ipython-input-26-74779de210e4> in step(self)
     79                 self)
     80         elif self.agent_type == 'T':
---> 81             if not self.observer.changed(self.agent_id):
     82                 self.observer.set_agent(
     83                     self.agent_id,

<ipython-input-26-74779de210e4> in changed(self, agent_id)
     45 
     46     def changed(self, agent_id):
---> 47         if self.prev_agents[agent_id].agent_type != self.agents[agent_id].agent_type:
     48             # been changed, can't change it back so skip it
     49             return True

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `deepcopy` you are copying the `observer` itself which is a reference on each of the agents, and those `observer` copies have `self.prev_agents = None` as you are about to set this attribute. In detail, line 20 `self.prev_agents = deepcopy(self.agents)`:

1. For each agent in `self.agents`, create a copy.
2. Each agent stores a reference `self.observer`.
3. Because we are doing a deep copy, we need to copy that observer as well.
4. The `observer` has various attributes among which there is `self.prev_agents`.
5. Since we are still computing the right hand side of `self.prev_agents = deepcopy(self.agents)`, `self.prev_agents` is still `None` (line 14).
6. So each of the agent copies now has a reference `self.observer` which is a copy of the original observer and that copy has `self.prev_agents is None`.

That's why in the subsequent call to `step` the agent references the wrong observer and thus the error. I don't see why you would want to copy the observer at all, so using `copy.copy` instead of `copy.deepcopy` should solve the problem.

Side note: deep copying each agent will also encounter a reference cycle of the form `agent -> observer -> self.agents -> agent` but [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) avoids this problem by keeping a memo dict of already copied objects.